# Copying a file from Downloads to Cups

Tags: printing

Forgive my ignorance, I am a complete but enthusiastic novice. I want to install two printers that are not on the repository but I have the necessary files. The folder is in my Downloads and I need to copy one file from it to the cups directory (it's a `pstoricohddst-gdi`).

Can anyone tell me in simple idiot proof language how to do this?

Comment: Do the printers not show up in CUPS if you go to a web browser and type in http://localhost:631 ?

Comment: Unfortunately not - for ref they are Ricoh sp112su and sp211.

Comment: My bad.  I meant to ask if they are seen when you do the Add Printer in http://localhost:631/admin/ ?  Do you have the PPD file?  As you step through the installation you can choose your own PPD.

Comment: When you say "I have the necessary files" it may be helpful to tell us which files you have and where you got them.

Comment: the file came from a respondent on this site and I have been looking for that QA session. The file contained sp100 and sp200 PPD, a check-requirement, a pstoricohddst-gdi file and an install file. but I cannot follow the install he posted here. Sorry but I did say I need an idiot guide. If you could tell me how to copy the pstoricohddst-gdi into the cups folder perhaps I can go from there.

Comment: You don't copy it in, you choose it during the installation and it will place the PPD where it needs to go.  Here is a decent step-by-step through the GUI installation of a printer:  https://linuxaria.com/article/how-to-add-a-printer-in-ubuntu-or-linux-mint-with-cups

Comment: Many thanks you were quite right the system found my ppd files.

Comment: I located the PPD files in my Downloads in 'Add Printer' and selected it but when it came to print test page it said the pstoricohddst-gdi file needed to be installed in the cups/filter folder.  So I am back to my original question. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a link on moving and copying

http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/move-copy-delete-files-linux/

the **filter** directory you want is in /usr/lib/cups so if get "inside" the directory where you want to start; (to paste a command into a terminal, right-click at the text prompt in the terminal; the flashing light; find PASTE in the menu that appears;)

```
cd Downloads
```

then `cp pstoricohddst-gdi /usr/lib/cups/filter`

should copy the file; you can confirm it is there with

```
cd /usr/lib/cups/filter
```

and then `ls`

which asks the system to LIST what is in that directory; and if it was successfully copied, you should see it listed